# django export large excel queryset

Tags: python, django, excel

I have a relatively large queryset and i want to export it into excel file i was useing the XLWT library and django streaming response with csv file.
when i export very large queryset of a table in sqldeveloper or navicat, the export operation is very fast but django's libraries is relatively slow. i think the excel write by row and column, or csv streaming response, write row by row in file but i looking for a way to write whole of queryset to excel.
is there a way to export whole of queryset to excel in python django?
Something that comes to my mind is call os command in python code to run export command in database but i not tested it.
thanks everybody

Answer (score 0):

I should have used pandas.
adjust and add my queryset in data frame and to_excel or to_csv.
thanks anyway